# Listview disable android ripple

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

Is possible to disable android ripple effect on ListView?
I have disabled it on iOS by this function:

```
onItemLoading(args: any) {
   if (ios) {
      const cell = args.ios;
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   } else if (android) {

   }
}
```

Is it possible on android too?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting selector on native android ListView widget upon loaded event.

```
onLoaded(event) { 
   if (event.object.android) {
     event.object.android.setSelector(new android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable());
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I am using Angular and VSCode show error: Property 'graphics' does not exist on type 'AndroidApplication'

Comment: The code was tested, if it doesn't work please share a Playground sample.

Comment: The error sounds like you are using Android Application instance, you are suppose to use android package.

Comment: See https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0MG3wv

Comment: You are not suppose to import android - [Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0MG3wv&v=2)